# Angular service that compiles objects from two controllers to create 'Content Feed'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services

I have two controllers for two sections of a potential website: 'Articles' and 'Resources'. I'd like to have a 'Feed' section that combines the objects from these two sections and lists them all. I'm using `ng-repeat` for all of this.

I'm not sure whether a service or a factory is more appropriate in this situation. I was thinking a factory might be more valuable so that I can have one method "synchronize" the posts with the controllers and one method, "GetFeed", that returns the object with the combined feeds.

I'm having trouble developing the architecture for this.

I have a detailed [codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/emjqgY) that has everything but the factory/service resolved for this concept. I'll detail the important components below as well:

Here is the markup (working):

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
  <h1>
    {{ article.title }}
  </h1>
  <pre>
    {{ article.date }}
  </pre>
    {{ article.description }}
</div>
```

The markup for the `resources` and `feed` sections are extrapolated from this and are working.

Here is the data that is currently stored in the controller:

```
app.controller('ArticlesCtrl', function($scope, FeedFactory) {

$scope.articles = {
  beer: {
    title: 'Beer',
    date: '1/1/15',
    description: 'Cold filter, goblet imperial hydrometer tulip     glass lagering. pub brewpub brewing malt extract goblet bock bock, abbey. adjunct ale                                           mash tun, bitter ester.'
  },
  liquor: {
    title: 'Liquor',
    date: '1/3/15',
    description: 'Screwdriver, "metaxas chartreuse," hayride cuba libre grand marnier suaza. Paradise mortlach the amarosa cocktail ramos gin fizz murphys.                                         Calvert johnny walker red.'
  }
}

});
```

And the object in question, `FeedFactory` that I want to compile `$scope.articles` from `ArticlesCtrl` and `$scope.resources` from `ResourcesCtrl`.

```
app.factory('FeedFactory', function() {
  return { 
    // some object that returns the all the posts from articles and resources
  }
});
```

To reiterate: What is the best architecture for compiling objects from two sections (articles, resources) and delivering them as a 'content feed'? I'd eventually like to sort them by date, but I'll save that for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put all your content in the FeedFactory, and filter it based on type. This would work perfectly with a NoSQL backend, where service.content really is a call to your server API. You could (and probably should) filter on the server as well, and return those objects in `service.getArticles()` and `service.getResources()`. This of course depends on how crazy big your content feed is going to be.

Here's how to do it with AngularJS' built in `$filter`:

```
app.factory('FeedFactory', function($filter) {
  var service = {};

  service.content = [
    {
       type: 'article',
       title: 'Hello there'
    },
    {
       type: 'resource',
       title: 'Yarr this be a resource'
    }
    //etc
  ];

  service.getArticles = function () {
    return $filter('filter')(service.content, {type:'article'});
  };

  service.getResources = function () {
    return $filter('filter')(service.content, {type:'resource'});
  };
  return service;
});
```

I edited your codepen for a working example here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEpgKg

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for. It makes sense to use a service, rather than a factory, right? Can you recommend a particular NoSQL backend (preferably a free one)?

Comment: I refer to .service, .factory, .value etc. all as services. It's really a matter of preference what you use, really :) I prefer to use factory. MongoDB is a popular NoSQL choice: http://www.mongodb.org/

Answer (score 0):

We use a pattern in our client side project that's basically the same as DDD, and use repositories to get all of our data. This has worked very well for us, and keeps things separate. Your controller should really just be the interaction between your other services and the UI. Thus you inject the repo in to the controller and have the repo know how to get the data, or if both concepts are really 2 different things then you have 2 repos injected and you combine the results together in the controller.

Here's a rough idea:

```
app.service("myRepo", function($http){
   getStuffById(id){
      return $http.get("somePath/" + id);
   }
}

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, myRepo){
   myRepo.getStuffById(1).then(function(myStuff){
      $scope.myStuff = myStuff;
   }
}
```

Comment: I agree, controllers should only communicate between DOM and Services or Database. I'm planning to migrate my info into Firebase or JSON soon, but the data is currently living in my controller. Can you provide any insight into how to do this - as a temporary solution?

Comment: Added example code. Sorry if it's not exactly right, we use Typescript, and I've gotten so familiar with that, that I no longer remember exactly how to do it in regular JS.